# Mosek: suppress printing "MOSEK Version 9.2.3..."

Tags: matlab, mosek

I am using Mosek in Matlab and I would like to suppress any printing after running an optimisation problem.

I have set `param.MSK_IPAR_LOG = 0;`. However, I still get the following message printed.

```
MOSEK Version 9.2.3 (Build date: ...)
Copyright (c) MOSEK ApS, Denmark. WWW: mosek.com
Platform: ...
```

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo(0)` every time you run `mosekopt`, for example `mosekopt('minimize echo(0)', prob, param)` and so on.

https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/toolbox/solver-io.html

Answer (score 0):

A work-around is to count how many characters it displays and then remove those characters.

```
fprintf(repmat('\b',1,n));
%where n is the number of characters to remove
```

This doesn't suppress the printing but it *removes* the printed characters instead.